# How to run Django unit tests against a postgre database

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Im using coverage.py and django-nose to run unit tests. All was working fine with the 'default' sqlite database. Yet when i swapped this out for a postgre database I get the following error:

**django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "authentication_user" does not exist**

In test_settings.py:

```
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': 5432,
            'NAME': 'testing_db',
            'USER': 'user_name',
            'PASSWORD': 'password'
        }
}
```

Command used to run tests (found in the 'tests' folder):

```
coverage run manage.py test tests
```

Oddly enough if i run an individual `TestCase` as follows, the test runs fine (error only occurs when running a collection of tests):

```
coverage run manage.py test tests.test_something
```

Any ideas of what is going wrong here?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution ? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: @Sam from what i can recall there may be an error in one of the test cases which will prevent the entire suite from running. I would try to run them one by one until you determine which one is problematic.

Answer (score -1):

right after you finished setting up the project and in order to go to ADMIN page, you had to execute the command:

> python manage.py createsuperuser

since you switched databases to postgres, you should run the command from project root folder in order to use the

> manage.py

script, and make a new superuser.
after that you should run a migration to the new DB and you done.
let me know how it went.

ref: [python superuser doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial02/)